# Symfony Stripe Disconnect after Payment

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments, session-cookies

in my application Symfony 5.4 and PHP 8.0, i'm using Stripe Payment Checkout https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout, after payment success or error my user need to be redirect.

'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/domain/projet/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}/domain/succes',
'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/domain/projet/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}/error',

But user is disconnect and i don't want user disconnect, sometime if we are lucky user is not disconnect after payment.

```
#[Route('/espace-client/payer/project/{idBilling}/{idProject}', name: 'final')]
public function stripePayment(int $idBilling, int $idProject)
{
    $project = $this->projectRepository->findOneById($idProject);
    $billing = $this->billingRepository->findOneById($idBilling);

    $YOUR_DOMAIN = 'https://127.0.0.1:8000';
    $productStripe[] = [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'unit_amount' => $billing->getPrice(),
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => $billing->getName(),
                'images' => null,
            ],
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
    ];
    Stripe::setApiKey($this->publicKey);
    $checkout_session = Session::create(
        [
        'line_items' => [[
            $productStripe,
        ]],
        'payment_method_types' => [
            'card',
        ],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/espace-client/projet/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}/paiement/succes',
        'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN.'/espace-client/projet/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}/erreur',
         ]
    );
    $billing->setStripeSessionId($checkout_session->id);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirect($checkout_session->url);
}
```

I tryied everyting but user is disconnected always and i don't know why.
Payment, checkout all is ok

Answer (score 0):

If your users get disconnected after the Stripe redirect, it usually means that one or more of the user’s cookies (such as their login or session cookie) are lost during the redirect process. And there are two common causes for this:

**A mismatch between HTTPS and HTTP protocols after the redirect.** For example if the user is browsing your website on HTTPS, but then gets redirected to a HTTP URL. To fix this, make sure all URLs involved use the same protocol.

**The `SameSite` attribute is set to `strict` on the cookies used for login or session.** If that’s the case, those cookies will not be included when the user is redirected back to your website because that redirect is considered a cross-site request. To fix this, change the `SameSite` attribute from `strict` to either `lax` or `none`. [More info here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-samesite).

Comment: cookie_samesite, that great, that work, i thinked the problem come from Stripe Checkout, i tryied to know stripe webhook, sorry and Thanks you <3